# passing double-quotes through weka machine learning

Tags: string, bash, escaping, weka, double-quotes

I am using `CLI` of Weka, namely, `Primer` and I have tried many different combo of passing several argument with no success. When I pass sth like this:

```
weka_options=("weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg -C 1.0 -N 0")
```

the program runs with no issue, but passing something like this:

```
weka_options=("weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg -C 1.0 -N 0 -I \"weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved -L 1.0e-3 -W 1 -P 1.0e-12 -T 0.001 -V\" -K \"weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.NormalizedPolyKernel -C 250007 -E 8.0\"")
```

with/withOut escape character and even single quoted `, brings me error in my bash scripts:

```
bash ./weka.sh "$sub_working_dir" $train_percentage "$weka_options" $files_string > $predictions
```

where `weka.sh` contains:

```
java -Xmx1024m -classpath ".:$WEKAPATH" $weka_options -t "$train_set" -T "$test_set" -c 53 -p 53
```

Here is what I get:

```
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?

Weka exception: Can't open file No suitable converter found for '0.001'!.
```

Can anyone pinpoint the issue?

Updated question: here is the codes:

```
    # Usage:
# 
# ./aca2_explore.sh working-dir datasets/*
# e.g.
# ./aca2_explore.sh "aca2-explore-working-dir/" datasets/*
#
# Place this script in the same folder as aca2.sh and the folder containing the datasets. 
# 
#
# Please note that:
#   - All the notes contained in aca2.sh apply
#   - This script will erase the contents of working-dir

# to properly sort negative floating numbers, independently of local language options

export LC_ALL=C

# parameters parsing

output_directory=$1

first_file_index=2
files=${@:$first_file_index}

# global constants

datasets=$(($# - 1))
output_row=$(($datasets + 3))
output_columns_range="2-7"
learned_model_mae_column=4
results_learned_model_mae_column=4

# parameters

working_dir="$output_directory"
if [ -d "$working_dir" ];
then
    rm -r "$working_dir"
fi
mkdir "$working_dir"

sub_working_dir="$working_dir""aca2-explore-sub-working-dir/"
path_to_results_file="$sub_working_dir""results.csv"

train_percentage=25

logfile="$working_dir""aca2_explore_log.csv"
echo "" > "$logfile"

reduced_log_header="Options,average_test_set_speedup,null_model_mae,learned_model_mae,learned_model_rmse,mae_ratio,R^2"

reduced_logfile="$working_dir""aca2_explore_reduced_log.csv"
echo "$reduced_log_header" > "$reduced_logfile"

sorted_reduced_logfile="$working_dir""aca2_explore_sorted_reduced_log.csv"

weka_options_list=(
"weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression -S 0 -R 1.0E-8"
"weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 100 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a"
"weka.classifiers.meta.AdditiveRegression -S 1.0 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.trees.DecisionStump"
"weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging -P 100 -S 1 -num-slots 1 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree -- -M 2 -V 0.001 -N 3 -S 1 -L -1 -I 0.0"
"weka.classifiers.meta.CVParameterSelection -X 10 -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR"
"weka.classifiers.meta.MultiScheme -X 0 -S 1 -B \"weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR \""
"weka.classifiers.meta.RandomCommittee -S 1 -num-slots 1 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree -- -K 0 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1"
"weka.classifiers.meta.RandomizableFilteredClassifier -S 1 -F \"weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.RandomProjection -N 10 -R 42 -D Sparse1\" -W weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk -- -K 1 -W 0 -A \"weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch -A \"weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last\"\""
"weka.classifiers.meta.RandomSubSpace -P 0.5 -S 1 -num-slots 1 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree -- -M 2 -V 0.001 -N 3 -S 1 -L -1 -I 0.0"
"weka.classifiers.meta.RegressionByDiscretization -B 10 -K weka.estimators.UnivariateEqualFrequencyHistogramEstimator -W weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -- -C 0.25 -M 2"
"weka.classifiers.meta.Stacking -X 10 -M \"weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR \" -S 1 -num-slots 1 -B \"weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR \""
"weka.classifiers.meta.Vote -S 1 -B \"weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR \" -R AVG"
"weka.classifiers.rules.DecisionTable -X 1 -S \"weka.attributeSelection.BestFirst -D 1 -N 5\""
"weka.classifiers.rules.M5Rules -M 4.0"
"weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR"
"weka.classifiers.trees.DecisionStump"
"weka.classifiers.trees.M5P -M 4.0"
"weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -I 100 -K 0 -S 1 -num-slots 1"
"weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree -K 0 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1"
"weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree -M 2 -V 0.001 -N 3 -S 1 -L -1 -I 0.0")

files_string=""

for file in ${files[@]}
do
    files_string="$files_string""$file"" "
done

#echo $files_string

for weka_options in "${weka_options_list[@]}"
do
        echo "$weka_options"
        echo "$weka_options" >> "$logfile"
        bash ./aca2.sh "$sub_working_dir" $train_percentage "$weka_options" $files_string
        cat "$path_to_results_file" >> "$logfile"

        result_columns=$(tail -n +"$output_row" "$path_to_results_file"  | head -1 | cut -d, -f"$output_columns_range")
        echo "$weka_options"",""$result_columns" >> "$reduced_logfile"

        echo "" >> "$logfile"
done

tail -n +2 "$reduced_logfile" > "$sorted_reduced_logfile"
sort --field-separator=',' --key="$results_learned_model_mae_column" "$sorted_reduced_logfile" -o "$sorted_reduced_logfile"".tmp"
echo "$reduced_log_header" > "$sorted_reduced_logfile"
cat "$sorted_reduced_logfile"".tmp" >> "$sorted_reduced_logfile"
rm "$sorted_reduced_logfile"".tmp"
```

where the file `aca2.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run this script as ./script.sh working-directory train-set-filter-percentage "weka_options" datasets/*
#
# e.g.
# Place this script in a folder together with a directory containing your datasets. Call then the script as 
# ./aca2.sh "aca2-working-dir/" 25 "weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression -S 0 -R 1.0E-8" datasets_folder/*
#
# NOTE: the script will erase the content of working-directory
#       for correct behaviour $WEKAHOME environment variable must be set to the folder containing weka.jar, otherwise modify the call to the weka classifier below
#
# To define the error measures used in this script, I made use of some of the notions found in this article:
# http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/MeasuringError.html


# parameters parsing

output_directory=$1
train_set_percentage=$2

if [ $train_set_percentage -lt 1 ] || [ $train_set_percentage -gt 100 ];
then
    echo "Invalid train set percentage: "$train_set_percentage
    exit 1
fi


weka_options=$3

first_file_index=4
files=${@:$first_file_index}

# global constants

predictions_characters_range_value="23-28"
predictions_characters_range_error="34-39"

tmp_dir="$output_directory"
if [ -d "$tmp_dir" ];
then
    rm -r "$tmp_dir"
fi
mkdir "$tmp_dir"

results_header="testfile,average_test_set_speedup,null_model_mae,learned_model_mae,learned_model_rmse,mae_ratio,R^2"
results_file=$tmp_dir"results.csv"

echo "$results_header" > "$results_file"

arff_header="% ARFF conversion of CSV dataset

@RELATION program

@ATTRIBUTE ...

@DATA"

# global constants

datasets_per_program=5
entries_per_dataset=128

train_set_instances_to_select=$((datasets_per_program*entries_per_dataset*train_set_percentage/100))

all_prediction="$tmp_dir""all_predictions.txt"

count=0
prediction_efficiency_ideal_avg=0

arff_header_file="$tmp_dir""arff_header.txt"
echo "$arff_header" > "$arff_header_file"



count=0

for filename in ${files[@]}
do
    echo "Test set: $filename"

    echo "$filename" >> "$all_prediction"

    cur_dir="$tmp_dir$filename.dir/"
    mkdir -p $cur_dir

    testfile=$filename

    train_set="$cur_dir""train_set.arff"

    echo "$arff_header" > $train_set

    selected_train_subset="$cur_dir""selected_train_subset.csv"

    for trainfile in ${files[@]}
    do
        if [ "$trainfile" != "$testfile" ]; then
#           filter train set to feed only top 25% for model generation
            sort --field-separator=',' --key=53 "$trainfile" -o "$selected_train_subset"
            head -$train_set_instances_to_select "$selected_train_subset" >> $train_set
        fi
    done

    test_set="$cur_dir""test_set.arff"

    #echo "$arff_header" > $test_set
    cp "$testfile" "$test_set"


    # This file will contain the full configuration space dataset relative to the test program
    complete_test_set="$cur_dir""complete_test_set.csv"
    cp "$test_set" "$complete_test_set"

    sort --field-separator=',' --key=53 "$test_set" -o "$test_set"
    head -8 "$test_set" > "$test_set"".tmp"
    mv "$test_set"".tmp" "$test_set"

    cur_prediction="$cur_dir""cur_prediction.tmp"

    # generate basis for predicted test set file by copying the actual test set, removing speedups
    predicted_test_set="$cur_dir""predicted_test_set.csv"
    cp "$test_set" "$predicted_test_set"
    cut -d, -f53 --complement "$predicted_test_set" > "$predicted_test_set"".tmp"
    mv "$predicted_test_set"".tmp" "$predicted_test_set"

    cat "$arff_header_file" "$test_set" > "$test_set"".tmp"
    mv "$test_set"".tmp" "$test_set"    

    java -Xmx1024m -classpath ".:$WEKAHOME/weka.jar:$WEKAJARS/*" $weka_options -t "$train_set" -T "$test_set" -c 53 -p 53 | tail -n +6 | head -8  > "$cur_prediction"

    predictions_file="$cur_dir""predictions.csv"
    cut -c"$predictions_characters_range_value" "$cur_prediction" | tr -d " " > "$predictions_file"

    paste -d',' "$actual_speedups" "$predictions_file" > "$predictions_file"".tmp"
    mv "$predictions_file"".tmp" "$predictions_file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost have this right. You were trying to do the right thing it looks like (or just getting accidentally close).

You **cannot** use a string for arbitrarily quoted arguments (this is [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).

You need to use an array instead. But you need an array with a separate element for *each* argument. Not just one argument.

```
weka_options=(weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg -C 1.0 -N 0)
```

or

```
weka_options=(weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg -C 1.0 -N 0 -I "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved -L 1.0e-3 -W 1 -P 1.0e-12 -T 0.001 -V" -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.NormalizedPolyKernel -C 250007 -E 8.0")
```

(I assume the string `weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved -L 1.0e-3 -W 1 -P 1.0e-12 -T 0.001 -V` is the argument to the `-I` flag and that the string `weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.NormalizedPolyKernel -C 250007 -E 8.0` is the argument to the `-K` flag. If that's not the case then those quotes likely want to get removed also.)

And then when you use the array you need to use `"${weka_options[@]}"` to get the elements of the array as individual quoted words.

```
java -Xmx1024m -classpath ".:$WEKAPATH" "${weka_options[@]}" -t "$train_set" -T "$test_set" -c 53 -p 53
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Etan, what If my `weka_options` were more than one option that I wanted to pass?

Comment: Are those not more than one option? Is that *entire* string one long option to the java module? If that entire string really needs to be passed to java as one long argument then what you had is probably what you wanted and you probably just need to quote `"$weka_options"` in the script when you use it.

Comment: sorry to confuse you, I meant, say, if I wanna explore 7-10 different machine learning option in this case: `weka_options_list=(
"weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression -S 0 -R 1.0E-8"
"weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 100 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a"
"weka.classifiers.meta.AdditiveRegression -S 1.0 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.trees.DecisionStump"
"weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging -P 100 -S 1 -num-slots 1 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree -- -M 2 -V 0.001 -N 3 -S 1 -L -1 -I 0.0"
"weka.classifiers.meta.CVParameterSelection -X 10 -S 1 -W)`

Comment: by the way, I tested you mentioned answer and its not working, it only takes the first string before the first argument and pass it to java

Comment: If you were writing the java command for that (or for the original) by hand what would it look like *exactly*?

Comment: `java -Xmx6024m -classpath ".:$WEKAPATH" weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg -C 1.0 -N 0 -I "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved -L 0.0010 -W 1 -P 1.0E-12 -T 0.0010 -V" -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.NormalizedPolyKernel -C 250007 -E 8.0" -t "train_set" -T "test_set"`

Comment: If that first `weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg -C 1.0 -N 0 -I` bit is not quoted like the other two bits then what I put in the answer should work... but as you are passing `"${weka_options[@]}"` to the shell script you will need to collect all the arguments and pass them on to the java call (simply using `weka_options=$3` will not work). Which means it needs to be the last argument on the shell script call so you can shift off the earlier arguments in the script and then use `"$@"` (or similar mechanisms).

Comment: Sure, I am uploading the files on the question

Comment: since I could only upload graphic files, I revised the question statement with the scripts.